# How to generate Private key, public key and address

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, dapps, javascript

I can't find any documentation online about doing this in Javascript other than [this](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english).

I want to know how does authentication work in a ethereum dApp's.. As per my understanding user seed somehow gets generated into a private key, then using  that private key to derive the public key and from that you derive the address.. does anyone have any further information on how this achieved with javascript or what is the architecture for this kind of setup.. any help on understanding it would be great.

i know how to generate the seed phrase etc with the js bip39 library after that im a bit stuck.

this is basically what i am attempting so far:

```
    const mnemonic = "vacant element sleep harsh stick else salt great kitten clutch salad subway"
    const privateKey = new Buffer( mnemonic )
    const publicKey = ethUtil.privateToPublic(privateKey).toString('hex')
    const address = ethUtil.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString('hex')
```

Comment: Is there a particular tool you're trying to match? I.e. do you want to create the same address(es) as some other tool given the same seed phrase?

Comment: Or is your goal just to produce a random private key (and address)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have extracted this code from [HD Wallet Provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js)

```
const bip39 = require('bip39');
const hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');

const mnemonic = '..';
const hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
const path = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0";
const wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(path).getWallet();
const address = `0x${wallet.getAddress().toString('hex')}`;

console.log(`Address: ${address}`);
```

Comment: Nice! Was hoping someone would come up with a better answer than mine :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

If you've already generated a seed equating to a private key, then you can probably get the rest of what you want from [Ethereum's GitHub repo](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util). (The same functionality is probably provided in the [BIP-39 JS code](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/blob/master/src/js/ethereumjs-util.js).)

Something along the lines of:

```
var utils = require('ethereumjs-util')
var privateKey = new Buffer(<from_seed>)
var publicKey = utils.privateToPublic(privateKey).toString('hex')
var address = utils.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString('hex')
```

**Edit:**

The above assumes you've already generated some derived private keys from your mnemonic. To get from the raw BIP-39 mnemonic to the above is a bit more involved. (I'm probably not best qualified to give a decent answer on JS code... Someone may have a better method than the below. As @smarx says, it's also not clear what your ultimate aims are.)

In short - from [`index.js`](http://From%20%60index.js%60) in the BIP-39 JS code - you'll need to:

- Get the derivation path (`getDerivationPath()`)
- Calculate the BIP32 Extended Key (`calcBip32ExtendedKey()`)
- Get the key (`bip32ExtendedKey.derive()`)
- From this, get the keypair (`key.keyPair`)

Then you can get your values [directly](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/blob/fcc7d121097189600a14d5f8247735cc88a9dbb2/src/js/index.js#L827):

```
var privKeyBuffer = keyPair.d.toBuffer(32);
privkey = privKeyBuffer.toString('hex');
var addressBuffer = ethUtil.privateToAddress(privKeyBuffer);
var hexAddress = addressBuffer.toString('hex');
var checksumAddress = ethUtil.toChecksumAddress(hexAddress);
address = ethUtil.addHexPrefix(checksumAddress);
privkey = ethUtil.addHexPrefix(privkey);
pubkey = ethUtil.addHexPrefix(pubkey);
```

The above might at least give you an idea of where to look to get further.

Comment: Okay, which is basically this answer...: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1063/52

Comment: its giving me the error that "private key length is invalid"

Comment: What are you feeding into the the `privateKey` buffer? (You'll need to use one of the derived private keys.)

Comment: im feeding in the mneumonic seed phrase, i thought the privated key was derived from it ? so this is basically what i feed into buffer  "vacant element sleep harsh stick else salt great kitten clutch salad subway"

Comment: I use bip39 for generating the seed

Answer (score 0):

If you use it in browser or React Native with Expo, try [ethers.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers), otherwise, you will introduce a lot of works here, since you have to access native code for using [react-native-randomBytes](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes)

with `ethers.js`, just run:

```
const wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```