# Creating ethereum account during user registration

Tags: web3js

There is a site with simple registration and user login. How can I create a new ethereum account for each new user and store the keys of these accounts in my database

Comment: You can use a HD wallet https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39384/how-to-generate-private-key-public-key-and-address

Comment: @Ismael Is it possible to use web3.eth.accounts.create()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const util = require("ethereumjs-util");

const privateKey = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
const publicAddr = "0x" + util.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString("hex");
```

Comment: And what commands can you make transactions between addresses?