# Generate ETH address with button on my website

Tags: addresses, cpp-ethereum

I'd like to open a website that I can easily generate an ETH address like this website: http://taschh.com/microworkers/cv/generate/
Of course, I will have all of ETH address and its private key.
I don't know how to do that. 
I have a normal website.
Please help me
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this chapter from "Mastering Ethereum" about Keys and Addresses:

https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/keys-addresses.asciidoc

Then look at some other answers on Stack Exchange:

[Is there any lightweight JS library that generates Ethereum addresses from 256-bit private keys?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/is-there-any-lightweight-js-library-that-generates-ethereum-addresses-from-256-b)

Comment: I have read it but I dont show how to creat website like http://taschh.com/microworkers/cv/generate/ . Could you show me more. Thank you